# Когда использовать паттерн Особый случай?

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования

В книге Чистый код в главе Обработка ошибок, есть упоминание паттерна ОСОБЫЙ СЛУЧАЙ. Автор предлагает вместо возвращения NULL, выдать исключение, либо возвращать объект особого случая. Вопрос: если в проекте достаточно много проверок на null; Стоит ли абсолютно для каждого класса, делать подкласс с особым случаем? Не является ли это overengineering?
Если нельзя так делать, то можно, пожалуйста, когда все таки стоит использовать данный паттерн, чтобы было эффективно

Comment: Ну тут надо по коду смотреть. Если `null` как результат является понятным случаем, то можно использовать его. Если ход работы кода при этом нужно прервать и перекинуть управление выше куда-то по иерархии, то исключение - самое то. Ну а если всё же нужно продолжить работу, а `null` не является достаточно понятным и информативным значением, то можно завести особый случай.

Answer (score 1):

Можешь орентироваться на следующие признаки:

1. **Часто встречающиеся проверки.** Если в коде очень много мест, где выполняется проверка на null для определенного типа объекта, и этот код разбросан по различным частям системы, это может быть признаком того, что стоит ввести особый случай.
2. **Семантика.** Если особый случай имеет четкую семантику в предметной области (например, пустой список, отсуствующий пользователь и т.д.), это может улучшить читаемость и понимание кода.
3. **Избавление от условных операторов.** Если возвращаемый "особый" объект может успешно выполнить то же поведение, что и реальный объект, без необходимости проверки на null (или другой проверки), это может упростить и улучшить код.

Когда скорее всего не стоит использовать этот паттерн:

1. **Не всегда нужен особый объект.** Если проверка на null встречается только в одном или двух местах, создание особого объекта может быть избыточным.
2. **Вычислительная стоимость.** Создание и управление особыми объектами также имеет свою цену, особенно если они сложные или требуют дополнительных ресурсов. Поэтому создавать для каждого интерфейса особый случай, наверное, не очень хорошая идея.
3. **Понимание кода.** Вводя в код особые объекты, мы можем увеличить сложность понимания кода. Либо просто запутать свой код. Поэтому здесь нужно взвешивать: принесёт ли это какую-то пользу? Сделает код проще или наоборот запутает его?